# Можно ли так строить СПП?

Tags: грамотная-речь, спп

В последнее время я стал обращать внимание на странное, на мой взгляд, использование определительного придаточного предложения с союзным словом "который" для описания некоего последующего действия, не влияющего на основное и не поясняющего его. Примеры:

**Произойдет повышение температуры, которая станет выше обычной для этого времени года.**

**После ОРВИ осталась температура, которая держалась в последующем на протяжении 3 месяцев.**

**В результате инцидента пострадала женщина, которая была госпитализирована.**
(Далее в тексте: В результате пожара пострадала 41-летняя женщина. Она была госпитализирована в лечебное учреждение с черепно-мозговой травмой и резаной раной руки.)

По-моему, если предложение построено правильно, всегда можно добавить «именно тот» перед «который». Например:

**Прозвенел будильник, (именно тот) который подарила мне моя бабушка.**

Но в трех первых предложениях вы не можете добавить «именно тот» без искажения смысла. Так можно ли таким образом построенные предложения считать правильными?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51524/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существуют два вида определительных придаточных: **выделительные и распространительные.**

**Выделительные придаточные** обозначают признак, который выделяет предмет из ряда однородных (именно тот, который), а **распространительные придаточные** просто сообщают об известном предмете дополнительную информацию (такие предложения легко преобразуются в два высказывания (тот, **который** и тот, **он**).

Отличительной особенностью распространительных придаточных является то, что они **не могут содержать указательного слова**: Взошло солнце, которое осветило всё вокруг. (Нельзя сказать: **то** солнце, которое...).

Comment: Спасибо! Кстати, в подтверждение Ваших слов нашел пример распространительного придаточного. -- Я приказал ехать на незнакомый предмет, который тотчас и стал подвигаться нам навстречу (А. С. Пушкин) -- А Пушкин, говорят , ошибок  не допускал :)

Answer (score 0):

Порой к союзному слову нельзя подставить "именно тот", но его можно заменить тем словом, к которому относится это союзное слово: Произойдет повышение температуры, которая станет выше обычной для этого времени года.
Которая в данном случае можно заменить словом температура: (которая) температура станет выше обычной для этого времени года.
Построение предложений, о которых вы говорили, правильное.
Также союзное слово нельзя убрать из предложения, а союзы можно убрать, это важное отличие союзов от союзных слов: Произойдет повышение температуры, станет выше обычной для этого времени года.
Смысл просто теряется.
Также союзное слово в предложении имеет логическое ударение, то есть оно не сливается в произношении с другим словом.

Comment: Исправьте, пожалуйста, "правильная" на "правильное":  Построение предложений, о которых вы говорили, правильное.

Comment: Благодарю за замечание.